# onActivityResult is not working

Tags: android, camera, gallery

currently am working on a task which take image from gallery/cammera and set it on a imageview,and i am using tabgroup activity.in this onActivityResult is not invoking.please check my code,and please  give me  some solution .

```
public class Create_Event extends BaseActivity{
    ImageView prof;
    String imagepath;
    Button next;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setLayoutId(this, R.layout.createevent);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new Handler() 
        {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MSG_CHOOSE_PHOTO: {
                   Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  //  startActivityForResult(i,Constants.MSG_CHOOSE_PHOTO);
                       System.out.println("fghdfgldgdjlgjdjgldfjgdfgdfjgl;f");
                           startActivityForResult(i,Constants.MSG_CHOOSE_PHOTO);
            }
                break;
        }
        }
                };

         initview();


    }
    public void initview() {
        prof=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.eventimg);
        prof.setOnClickListener(this);
        next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
          if(Constants.getPicture_path().toString().length()>0)
           {
            prof.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Constants.getPicture_path().toString()));
           }


          registerForContextMenu(prof);
    }

      public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose Image from"); 
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Gallery"); 
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "camera"); 
           }   
           @Override 
           public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
       { 
            if(item.getTitle()=="Gallery")
            {
                function1(item.getItemId());
            } 
             else if(item.getTitle()=="camera")
            {
                function2(item.getItemId());
             }  
            else
            {
            return false;
            } 
             return true; 
       }
       private void function1(int itemId)
       {
           mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.MSG_CHOOSE_PHOTO);




       }
       private void function2(int itemId)
       {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "/mnt/sdcard/profile_image.jpg");
            imagepath="/mnt/sdcard/montacts_profile_image.jpg";
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
       } 








        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee;f");

            if (requestCode == Constants.MSG_CHOOSE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                imagepath=picturePath;

                Constants.setPicture_path(picturePath);

                     //  Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
                        //profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));
                prof.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                    }
            else if(requestCode == 1){

                if(data != null)
                {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    photo = photo.createScaledBitmap(photo, 80, 80, false);
                    prof.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }

    }


   public void onClick(View view) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.eventimg:
        {
            //Intent i=new Intent(this,New_imgsel.class);
            //startActivity(i);

        }
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
        {


        }
            break;
        }
   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(item.getTitle()=="Gallery")
 {
      function1(item.getItemId());
 } 
 else if(item.getTitle()=="camera")
 {
      function2(item.getItemId());
 }
```

function1 and function2 are never called since you are comparing in the wrong way the string. You have to use `equals` or `eqaulsIgnoreCase`

```
 if(item.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Gallery"))
 {
      function1(item.getItemId());
 } 
 else if(item.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("camera"))
 {
      function2(item.getItemId());
 }
```

with `==` you compare the address of the Strings

Comment: it is not working ,i make the change as you mentioned.before also am able to enter the handler and print the line     System.out.println("fghdfgldgdjlgjdjgldfjgdfgdfjgl;f");  and from this it calling the onActivityResult,but its not calling here,am uisng tabgroup activity.plz help me/

Comment: what does "it is not working" mean. I doubt I could work before you apported the changes I suggested you

Comment: sorry.is there any way to solve this,plz give me some suggestion.

Comment: sorry for what ? Can you at tell me what does not work or what do you expect?

Comment: actually i need to set the selected image from gallery or camera to imageview,i can select the photo from gallery  or take the photo,but after that nothing is happen just finishes to my home activity.i think onActivityResult is not calling.and i am using tabgroup activity thats why it is extends the BaseActivity.

Comment: in onActivityResult print the value of  requestCode and resultCode

Comment: it is not printing anything ,i given the print statements almost everywhere,but its not printing.i think this method is not calling,when i selected the image from gallery it just close the galleryview and return to my activity.

Comment: what's BaseActivity? Have you override onActivityResult inside it?

Comment: no i didnt override,its a baseclass for all the tabgroupactivites

Comment: ah you are using a TabActivity? Do you know it has been deprectad lot of time ago? "google for TabActivity onActivityResult not called"

Comment: is there any solution for resolve this,because my 99% of prjt is done in tabactivity only,i cant change it,so any other solution for this.

Comment: you should call getParent().startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult in your BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

Call startActivityForResult from the parent activity and catch the result there, too.